# Google Plus Get Friends List for android application

Tags: android, google-plus

In My android app I was implemented Signup using google plus and it working fine.
Now I want to get active google plus user friends list(People in his circle).

I google it and found some solution like -

```
plusClient.loadVisiblePeople(new OnPeopleLoadedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPeopleLoaded(ConnectionResult arg0, PersonBuffer arg1,
                String arg2) {
            Log.i("Tdat", ""+arg0);
        }
    }, null);
```

and

```
GPConnectActivity.getPlusClient().loadPeople(new OnPeopleLoadedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPeopleLoaded(ConnectionResult arg0, PersonBuffer arg1,
                String arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }, "me");
```

but not found any solution.Can you please give me a way where I can get list of google plus friends.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use PersonBuffer to fetch data.

```
PersonBuffer personBuffer = peopleData.getPersonBuffer();
try 
{
    int count = personBuffer.getCount();
    Log.d(TAG, count + "");

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        Person person = personBuffer.get(i);
        Log.d(TAG, "Display name: " +personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName());
    }
}
finally
{
    personBuffer.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,can you explain what is peopleData in your answer.

Comment: implements your activity by using ResultCallback<LoadPeopleResult>. There is override method onResult in this method you get peopleData.

Comment: @ Sundeep Badhotiya i want to know LoadPeopleResult is deprecated. why?